# Prolog: Check if list of tuples is a function

Tags: function, prolog, forall

I want to check, if a list L of tuples (x1,y1) has the function property:

```
∀(x1,y1),(x2,y2) ∈ L (x1=x2  y1 = y2)
```

I tried to solve it with the following predicate:

```
m_Function(L) :-
    ((member(M1, L), member(M2, L), 
    M1 = (X1, Y1), M2 = (X2, Y2), X1 = X2) 
    -> Y1 = Y2).
```

the problem of that is, that e.g. the input

```
L = [(p, q),  (p, r)]
```

results in true.

The trace of my debug shows me I more exactly realised the statement:

```
∃(x1,y1),(x2,y2) ∈ L (x1=x2  y1 = y2)
```

trace:

```
 T Call: (8) m_Function([(p, q),  (p, r)])
   Call: (8) m_Function([(p, q),  (p, r)]) ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:member(_5074, [(p, q),  (p, r)]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member((p, q), [(p, q),  (p, r)]) ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:member(_5074, [(p, q),  (p, r)]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member((p, q), [(p, q),  (p, r)]) ? creep
   Call: (9) (p, q)=(_5060, _5062) ? creep
   Exit: (9) (p, q)=(p, q) ? creep
   Call: (9) (p, q)=(_5066, _5068) ? creep
   Exit: (9) (p, q)=(p, q) ? creep
   Call: (9) p=p ? creep
   Exit: (9) p=p ? creep
   Call: (9) q=q ? creep
   Exit: (9) q=q ? creep
 T Exit: (8) m_Function([(p, q),  (p, r)])
   Exit: (8) m_Function([(p, q),  (p, r)]) ? creep
```

Is their in prolog some elegant way e.g. with some "for all"-quantifier which I can use to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: After taking a quick glace and not looking at the details I would suspect that you used `=` where `==` is needed. I.e.  `=` is unification, `==` is comparison.

Comment: If this were my code I would not use list but ordered [ordsets](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/ordsets.pl). See: [What is wrong with intersection/3 and friends?](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=intersection/3)

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I optimized it a little bit into: 
m_Function(L) :-
    ((member((X, Y1), L), member((X, Y2), L)) 
    -> Y1 == Y2).
But the general problem is still appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forall/2`.

```
m_Function(L) :-
    forall((member((X, Y1), L), member((X, Y2), L)), Y1 == Y2).
```

> `forall(Condition, Action)` succeeds if for all alternative bindings of Condition, Action can be proven. It is equivalent to `\+(Condition, \+ Action)`.

Comment: `L=[(f1,1),(f1,Z)],forall( (member((X,Y1),L), member((X,Y2),L)), Y1 = Y2).
L = [(f1, 1),  (f1, Z)].` vs. `L=[(f1,1),(f1,Z)],forall( (member((X,Y1),L), member((X,Y2),L)), Y1 == Y2).
false.`

Comment: @GuyCoder: Yes `==` is correct. `forall` doesn't bind any thing but still unifies variables. Thank you.